# How to make "provided" scope working on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, provider, dagger

How to make "provided" scope working for dagger on Android Studio?
After run of my project I have this issue:
`Module adapter for class com.example.Module could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.`

My gradle is below

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    provided
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'
            debuggable false
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['/src/main/assets']
            compileClasspath += [configurations.provided]//it doesn work, Error: Could not find property 'compileClasspath' on source set main.
        }
    }


}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
}
```

Top gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `compileClasspath` doesn't work is because the Android plugin for Gradle uses its own source sets: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html

BTW, the Android plugin for Gradle also creates a `provided` configuration so you shouldn't have to configure anything.

That being said, you should use the `android-apt` plugin and its `apt` configuration instead of the `provided` configuration: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt (see the Q/A in the readme for why you should prefer `apt` to `provided`)

Comment: doesn't work, I added: `dependencies {classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'} apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'  ...   apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'` But issues still is `Module adapter could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.`

Comment: Hmm, you may have to manually enable annotation processing in Android Studio.

Comment: how to do that on Android Studio?